# Populate Ajax response with clickable elements that fires another Ajax with correct parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a function running an Ajax call that receives data and populate that as a table.
The response contains some rows with data and i now want to add a small fontawsome icon that when clicked fires another function with a parameter.

So i have this:

```
var latestprecasedata = '';
function getPreCaseData() {

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "case.aspx/GetPreCase",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response.d != null) {
                var data = response.d;
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#PreCaseTblBody").html("");
                for (var i in data) {

                    $("#PreCaseTblBody").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].pSubject + "</td><td><span class='preplus' id='" + data[i].pID + "'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></span></td><td>-</td></tr>");

                }
                if (latestprecasedata !== response.d) {
                    $("#precasestatus").removeClass("titleupd1").addClass("titleupd2");
                    latestprecasedata = response.d;
                }
                else {
                    $("#precasestatus").removeClass("titleupd2").addClass("titleupd1");
                }
            }

            $("#PreCaseTblBody tr:odd").css('background-color', '#f9f9f9'); //
            $("#PreCaseTblBody tr:even").css('background-color', '#f1ffee');
            setTimeout(getPreCaseData, 10000);
        }
    });

}
```

This works and every 10 seconds data is repopulated. (Maybe not the fastest solution, but it works..)

As you all can se i have a span with class=preplus and id of a unique value coming from my Ajax response. When inspecting the page i can see that every row from my Ajax response have a unique id.

For example two row looks like this:

```
<tr><td>Cables</td><td><span class="preplus" id="4815269"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Skrews</td><td><span class="preplus" id="4815269"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></td></tr>
```

So now i have the data populated with span containing a unique id that i want to pass to another function.

I've tried span, div, buttons but the only one time I actually got a event fire was when i placed my second function inside the

```
for (var i in data) {
```

... and i know, that's not right at all because all rows contained the last id obviously...

So my other function resides outside my first function and look like this (I've tried many different methods to get the id of my span but for now, I'm here)

```
$(".preplus").click(function () {
    var qID = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "case.aspx/UpdateQ",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'qid':'" + qID + "','pm':'plus'}",
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Your elements are dynamically created so you need to bind it some static element i.e : `$(document).on("click",".preplus",function () { //yourcodehere..}}` see if that works

Comment: Wait what... I'm sure that I tried that, almost, maybe, probably... Oh well you're spot on @Swati. Works lika a charm. Thanks!